# Pandas Multi Index Division

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a Multi Index dataframe that looks like

```
                            Mid
Strike  Expiration  Symbol  
167.5   2022-02-11  AAPL170 5.4
170     2022-02-11  AAPL170 3.1
        2022-02-18  AAPL170 4.525
        2022-02-25  AAPL170 5.25
        2022-03-04  AAPL170 6.00
172.5   2022-02-11  AAPL172 1.265
        2022-02-18  AAPL172 2.91
175     2022-02-11  AAPL175 0.265
        2022-02-18  AAPL175 1.695
```

so it is a multi index with the index of `strike` `expiration` and `symbol`, and then `mid` is just a column name, and NOT an index. I have a few other columns but they are not important for now. These are sorted in increasing value from the first index, I'm hoping to divide each `Mid` row by the next row below it, but only within each individual `strike` index. Currently, I am doing

```py
df['ratio'] = (df['mid'] / df['mid'].shift(-1))
```

and it works to give me a new column of all the divisions, but I'm running into problems where, for example, the `167.5 2022-02-11` row is getting divided by the `170 2022-02-11` row, and I need those to remain separated by index.

My goal is after this division is done, to be able to search for any ratios that are above a cutoff, ex. 0.5, and output what was divided to a new dataframe, so something similar to

```
Strike  Expirations                Symbol    Ratio
170     2022-02-11 / 2022-02-18    AAPL170   0.685
```

If someone could advise on both parts, I'd greatly appreciate it but I primarily need the first part fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `pct_change`:

```
new_df = df.groupby(level=0).pct_change(-1) + 1
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                                Mid
Strike Expiration Symbol           
167.5  2022-02-11 AAPL170       NaN
170.0  2022-02-11 AAPL170  0.685083
       2022-02-18 AAPL170  0.861905
       2022-02-25 AAPL170  0.875000
       2022-03-04 AAPL170       NaN
172.5  2022-02-11 AAPL172  0.434708
       2022-02-18 AAPL172       NaN
175.0  2022-02-11 AAPL175  0.156342
       2022-02-18 AAPL175       NaN
```

For debugging, you can try something like:

```
for _, d in df.groupby(level=0):
    try:
        d.pct_change()
    except:
        print(d)
        break
```

Comment: Ok this looks really promising. I got a ZeroDivisionError somewhere, which I was getting at one point previously too but stopped once I tried the division I posted above. Is there a way to circumvent this? Possibly changing all zeros to NaN first with numpy?

Comment: Hmm.. I tried changing all values to zero and cannot reproduce. Which version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: ```pandas 0.24.2``` I'm confused too since originally dividing every row by the row after it didn't error and a zero would have popped up then too

Comment: Can you try updating? It's really old version and I don't have an environment to reproduce :P. You can also try replacing zeros to very small number and revert them later.

Comment: Will do right now, also updating ipykernel since old version doesn't allow debugging in vscode apparently. Will update soon if it worked

Comment: I'm on 1.3.5 now, still getting the same error though of divide by zero

Comment: Sorry but it's really hard to help when a problem is not reproducible...

Comment: Is it possible to upload a csv to stackoverflow or is that frowned upon? I have my entire dataframe being read to a csv, even though visually I couldn't find any zeros either after a bit of scrolling. Thanks for the help though

Comment: I don't think you can upload a file to a question. You can post a link to download it but since downloading a file isn't always safe, it is not really recommended. How big is your data? Let me update to target a sub data to post

Comment: It is 917 rows by 10 columns right now. I searched it again, found zeros on 4 rows, the way the original command I did handled them is throwing inf in the column but not erroring. I ran ```df.loc[df['mid'] == 0, 'mid'] = np.nan``` and it still worked, replacing the zeros as ```nan```, but your line is still erroring. Hmm...

Comment: Try uploading somewhere, make a link and post it. Let me take a look

Comment: Ok so I tried the debugging line you sent me, and it errors out on 172.5. The new values are ```172.5  2022-02-11 AAPL172  0.91
       172.5 2022-02-18 AAPL172 2.59 ``` and that's where it breaks, I wonder if its treating the 0.91 as a zero somehow? Even though a ```dtype``` shows its a float64

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/CocaKolev/filesForStackOverflow) is a link with the CSV.

Comment: It had nothing to do with `mid`... It comes from the `inTheMoney`, where you had to `False/False`. Either you can `df["mid"].groupby(level=0).pct_change(-1) + 1`, or do `df.astype(float).groupby(level=0).pct_change(-1) + 1`

Comment: Stackoverflow being down was a surprise, but it worked! I did not realize it was dividing every column rather than only the mid column....why did it work on all the ```True/True``` though? And how did you come to that conclusion from the error message, I could've saved us a lot of time if I had caught that. Really appreciate it though.

Comment: `True` is treated as 1 in arithmetic whereas `False` is 0 ;)